# CSS Circle Working in Every Browser - EXCEPT Chrome

Tags: css

Okay, so this is a first - my CSS is working in all tested browsers...except Chrome.

I am attempting to render a simple circle in a div.

Example is: http://redappledev2.wpengine.com/ The login icon in the upper right hand corner of the header (circle with the user image).

In Firefox, IE, Safari the circle renders as a typical circle.
The current css is: `border-radius: 25px;` but the expected result also occurs when the css is `border-radius: 50%;`

From what I can peg down - it looks like in Chrome the problem is that the parent container - an A tag - the height is to short which is based on it's font size - currently `20px`. The font size cannot be increased, but in testing when I increase the size - the a tag's height increases and the circle border is rendered as a true circle and not an eclipse.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way of rendering the circle border around the user icon?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you change `div.icon-circle` from `display:inline` to `display:inline-block` things start to appear as you intend in Chrome.

I just used the DOM inspector to tweak some of your styles and got to a circle with the following style rule:

```
.icon-circle{
   border:1px solid #627F9A;
   border-radius: 25px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0px 5px 2px 4px;
   position: relative;
   top: 2px;
 }
```

Good luck with your site

Comment: dude! As my pop use to say, you're a Gentleman and a Scholar. Not sure why inline-block was the necessary componenet - but that fixed it in Chrome and did not break it in other tested browsers. Thank you again!